# Password mismatch between SQL Server Management Studio and config file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssms

When I connect to my local instance of SQL Server Express using SQL Server Management Studio I get a screen with the password automatically filled in as per this image:

[image]

I cannot remember what the password is. From this screen it appears to have 15 characters though.

I also have a Web app that connects to this database using ADO.Net. The Connection string is stored in the config file. Here I have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" xdt:Transform="Insert" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Scoreboard;User ID=sa;Password=abc1234" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The password here is 7 characters long (I've switched it to abc1234 for the purpose of displaying here)

I have a similar scenario with a database that I have on my web site's hosting server. i.e. my web app has a displayed 7 character password but my SSMS log-in has a 15 character password saved at start up. When I try and log in to that account using the 7 digit password it doesn't work.

What's going on here? I presume a single log-in name can only have one valid password and if so why is there the mismatch between the number of characters between the config files and the SSMS log-in screen?

For the record I can connect to the database from both the web app and SSMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a security trick that some programs use. You cannot rely on the number of stars. It just means there is a password that was remembered.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string includes this part:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

When means it is using Windows Authentication to connect and the username/password are being ignored. To do the same in SQL Server Management Studio, change the dropdown from `SQL Server Authentiation` to `Windows Authentication`. That way, you are connecting with your Windows account details rather than a SQL Server password.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS mask saved password. It always show 15 stars no matter what is the length of actual password is.

For security reasons, one should not use SA credentials in connection string. Rather make a dedicated login per application.